# Characterisation Fibration

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

I have a question about a remark which provides an equivalent characterisation for (weak) Serre fibration:

By "classical" definition a map $p:X \to Y$ is a (weak) Serre Fibration if it has following homotopy lifting property:

For every diagramm

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\{0\} \times I^{n-1} @>{a}  >> X   \\
@VViV  @VVpV   \\
I^n @>{b}>> Y 
\end{CD}
$$

there exist $l:I^n \to X$ such that $a = l \circ i$ and $b = p \circ l$ holds.

But in a remark (source: "Einführung Topology" by Laures, Szymik; page 197, German edition) is mentioned that there exist an equivalent characterisation:

A map $p: X \to Y$ is fibration if it has homotopy lifting property for all inclusions $incl: \{0\} \times I^{n-1} \cup I \times \partial I^{n-1} \to \{0\} \times I^{n-1}$.

My question is why is this condition equivalent to the "classical" one?

The author says that it's because there exist an automorphism of $I^n$ which embedds $\{0\} \times I^{n-1} \cup I \times \partial I^{n-1} $ to$ \{0\} \times I^{n-1}$. The construction is already clear to me, but not why this provides the equivalence of this two characterisation of fibration property.

Here the original excerpt (I don't found an English version):

[image]

Comment: Are you sure what you have written is correct? It would make more sense if $i:\{0\}\times I^n\to I^{n+1}$ and if $\text{incl}:\{0\}\times I^{n-1}\cup I\times \partial I^{n-1}\to I^n$?

Comment: Your first remark is of course correct, in case of the second one I'm not sure... I attatched above the original excerpt

Comment: I think that it comes from morphism described in Abb 9.4, not the canonical embedding...

Comment: Maybe what is meant is that instead of lifting the inclusion $i:\{0\}\times I^{n-1}\to I^n$, you can also lift $i':\{0\}\times I^{n-1}\cup I\times\partial I^{n-1}\to I^n$. The automorphism then shows that these two embeddings are equivalent. This is the only way I could make sense of this.

Comment: Equivalent in which way?

Comment: ...that you can identify $ \{0\}\times I^{n-1}\cup I\times\partial I^{n-1}$ with $\{0\}\times I^{n-1}$? If I understand it correctly then it seems that the restruction of this automorphism to $ \{0\}\times I^{n-1}\cup I\times\partial I^{n-1}$ provides an isomorphism to $\{0\}\times I^{n-1}$ or do you mean it in other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\phi$ the automorphism of $I^n$ described above, and $i,i'$ the obvious inclusions such that the left square commutes:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\{0\}\times I^{n-1}\cup I\times\partial I^{n-1} @>{\text{incl}} >\sim> \{0\} \times I^{n-1} @>{a}  >> X   \\
@VVi'V @VViV  @VVpV   \\
I^n @>{\phi}>\sim> I^n @>b>> Y
\end{CD}
$$

Then if $i$ can be lifted to some $\ell:I^n\to X$ such that the diagram commutes, then we also have $\ell\circ \phi$ lifting $i'$. Conversely, if $i'$ can be lifted with some $\ell':I^n\to X$, then $\ell'\circ \phi^{-1}$ is a lifting of $i$.

Comment: with $incl$ you mean the morphism $\{0\} \times I^{n-1} \cup I \times \partial I^{n-1} \to \{0\} \times I^{n-1}$ ...the description Abb 9.4 states just that it's an isomorphism,right?

Comment: Yes, $\text{incl}$ is an isomorphism.